# how fix encoding on java

Tags: java, sql-server, encoding, glassfish

Good afternoon,

I'm trying resolve the classic encoding error in java, but I don't know what to do...

I try:

```
add on jsp: <%@page contentType="text/html"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

use "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" no select(sqlserver)

add "CharacterSet=UTF-8" on String conection of jdbc

add response.setContentType("application/json"); and response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");  on servlet
```

but nothing works!!!!

SGBD: SQL Server
Server: GlassFish

Exemple record of database "EstÃƒÂ¡"

what can I do?

Comment: Can you determine what part of the application causes the probem? Are records stored in the DB properly and just displayed wrong, or the problem is just when you display the values? Is encoding correct when manually inserting records into the DB?

Comment: on may database :"EstÃƒÂ¡" and I nedd show "então", I do some tests in other language "PHP" and I resolve this whith this code "header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');", ut in java didn't work

Comment: How are you inserting records into your DB? Using jdbc in your application? What happens if you insert the "então" record manually, without using your application? Is the record thrn stored properly and then displayed improperly?

Comment: other application do insert on database, so I don´t know how, I'm only consume this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have `jtds` parameter `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false`

One solution is to change it to `true`. If not then:

`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is `CP-1252 (Windows-1252)` encoding, so to search in database you need to encode your Unicode string to `Windows-1252`:

```
new String(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Windows-1252")
```

Vice versa after read from database:

```
new String(value.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8")
```